# En esta función Javascript con sentencia switch no funcionan los case de cada condicional sino solo el default y no logro entender el por qué

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, function, switch

Tengo este código, que pregunta al usuario que producto desea, pero todavía no logro que en switch y de acuerdo a lo que ingrese el usuario, ya sea “falda, "short", "jean" o "sweater", se cumpla el case respectivo puesto que siempre arroja el alert 'no es un prooducto valido'

```
class Producto {
  constructor(nombre, precio, cantidad){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.precio = precio;
      this.cantidad = cantidad;
  }
  vender(){
      let calcular = this.cantidad*this.precio;
      return calcular;
  }
  mostrarInfo(totalCalculo){
      console.log(`Usted escogió ${this.cantidad} ${this.nombre}(s) con un valor de $${totalCalculo} `);
  }
}

let nombre = prompt ('¿Que producto desea escoger? Productos disponibles: falda, short, jean y sweter')

let cantidad = parseInt (prompt ('¿cuantos desea?'))

const producto2 = new Producto(nombre, 70, cantidad);
const producto3 = new Producto(nombre, 40, cantidad);
const producto1 = new Producto(nombre, 60, cantidad);
const producto4 = new Producto(nombre, 15, cantidad);

function escoger() {
    switch(nombre) {
      case "falda":
      return producto1

      case "short":
      return producto2

      case "jean":
      return producto3

      case "sweter":
      return producto4

      default:
      alert ('no es un producto valido')
      break;
    }
}
nombre = producto1
total = nombre.vender();
nombre.mostrarInfo(total);
escoger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Se ejecuta `default` porque el switch se ejecuta con la variable `nombre` que inicialmente es un `string`, pero la reasignas a un `Producto` en la línea:

```
nombre = producto1
```

Por lo tanto, `nombre` no es ni `"falda"`, ni `"shorts"` ni si quiera del mismo tipo.

Comment: Ok, entiendo @Mateo. Pero el problema que es que cuando elimino la línea donde se iguala nombre = prodcuto1 en seguida salta un error por consola "Uncaught TypeError: nombre.vender is not a function"... ¿por qué sucede esto? ¿mas fácil es que reasigne números a los case y dentro de cada case respectivo iguale el numero con el producto? ¿o el problema está en la variable nombre que va con el case?

Comment: Porque la función `vender` la tienen las instancias de la clase `Producto`. `producto1` sí contiene una instancia de la clase `Producto`. En cuanto a tu pregunta del switch, así como strings está bien. Pero es recomendable que uses un parámetro `nombre` en lugar de la variable local `nombre`.

Answer (score 0):

Se ejecuta default porque no le envías ninguna valor a nombre

```
function escoger() {
    switch(nombre) {
      case "falda":
      return producto1

      case "short":
      return producto2

      case "jean":
      return producto3

      case "sweter":
      return producto4

      default:
      alert ('no es un producto valido')
      break;
    }
}
```

Al no enviarle el valor a la función `escoger()` y pasar por el `switch`, no coincide con ninguno de los casos declarados y toma default, deberías llamar la función `escoger()` pasándole el valor de nombre.

Ejemplo:

````
let nombre:string="falda";
escoger(nombre);

function escoger(nombre) {
    switch(nombre) {
      case "falda":
      return producto1

      case "short":
      return producto2

      case "jean":
      return producto3

      case "sweter":
      return producto4

      default:
      alert ('no es un producto valido')
      break;
    }
}

```

en este caso obtendrás producto1
````